# Cannot ALTER user password using psycopg2

Tags: python-2.7, psycopg2

Updating a user's password with psycopg2 appears to run successfully, but the password remains unchanged.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='my_db' user='my_user' host='localhost' password='dbpass'")

cur = conn.cursor()

update_password_query = """ALTER USER my_user WITH PASSWORD %(password)s"""
cur.execute(update_password_query, {"password": new_password})
```

The execute statement returns `None`, which is expected for a successful query.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I needed to do a

```
conn.commit()
```

After the execute to get the changes to stick.

From the documentation http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html:

> commit()
> Commit any pending transaction to the database.
>
> By default, Psycopg opens a transaction before executing the first command: if commit() is not called, the effect of any data manipulation will be lost.
>
> The connection can be also set in “autocommit” mode: no transaction is automatically open, commands have immediate effect.

Also see [Use python to execute line in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780782/use-python-to-execute-line-in-postgresql)